# Amazon Redshift get all keys from JSON

Tags: amazon-redshift

I looked at the documentation of Amazon redshift and I'm not able to see a function which will give me what I want.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/json-functions.html

I have a column in my database which contains JSON like this

{'en_IN-foo':'bla bla', 'en_US-foo':'bla bla'}

I want to extract all keys from json which have foo. So I want to extract

en_IN-foo
en_US-foo

How can I get what I want? The closest to my requirement is JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT function but that can only extract the key when you know the key name. in my case I want all keys which have a pattern but I don't know the key names.

I also tried abandoning the JSON function way and going the REGEX way. I wrote this code

```
select distinct regexp_substr('{en_in-foo:FOO, en_US-foo:BAR}','[^.]{5}-foo')
```

but this finds only the first match. I need all the matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redshift is not flexible with JSON, so I don't think getting keys from an arbitrary JSON document is possible. You need to know the keys upfront.

### option 1

If possible change your JSON document to have a static schema:

```
{"locale":"en_IN", "foo": "bla bla"}
```

Or even

```
{"locale":"en_IN", "name": "foo", "value": "bla bla"}
```

### Option 2

I can see that your prefix *may be* known to you as it looks like the locale. What you could do is to create a static table of locales, and then `CROSS JOIN` it with your JSON column.

`locales_table`:

```
Id | locale
----------------
1  |  en_US
2  |  en_IN
```

The query would look like this:

```
SELECT
   JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(json_column, locale || '-foo', TRUE) as foo_at_locale
FROM json_table 
  CROSS JOIN locales_table
WHERE foo_at_locale IS NOT NULL
```